# How to Access Node API within Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, adonis.js

I have a three tier application on Docker tat consists of the following:
1. An Adonis app to server as the api for the application
2. A MongoDB database
3. A NuxtJS app for the client application.

When I run the application locally with `docker-compose up` it seems to start up just fine. However, when I try to access the api with postman (localhost:3333) or try to access the Next app on my browser (localhost:3000/), I get a "Could not get any response" error and a "Cannot open the page error" respectively.

I have tried exposing the ports within each component's Dockerfile, in addition to specifying port mappings on the docker-compose.yml file.

Here is my Dockerfile for the API application

```
# The API application

FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR home/api

COPY ./server-api/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY  ./server-api .

EXPOSE 3333

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is the Dockerfile for the NuxtJS application

```
# The Web application

FROM node:latest
WORKDIR home/app

COPY ./web-client/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY ./web-client .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:

  api:
    build: ./server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"

  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: NoneOfYourBusiness

  web:
    build: ./web
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

When I send a GET request to "localhost:3333/" I expect to get a response of "test". However, I am getting a "Could not get any response" error from Postman instead.

When I go to "localhost:3000/" on by browser, I expect to get a page. Instead, it is saying it cannot connect to the server.

Comment: `localhost` is always "this container".  Use the other container's name in the `docker-compose.yml` file (_e.g._, `api`) as a host name instead.

Comment: So, your saying in my browser/postman, I should call api:3333 and web:3000/ instead of localhost:3333 and localhost:3000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your machine:

You should be able to use `localhost:3333` with your current setup. You can double check if a program is listening on the port 3333 (`lsof -i:3333` on linux).

From inside your docker:

Set up networks and use the container names to call them, example

```
version: '3'

networks:
    back:

services:

  api:
    build: ./server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    networks:
      - back
  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: NoneOfYourBusiness
    networks:
      - back
  web:
    build: ./web
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - back
```

From the `web` container, you could call `api:3333` for the api.

BTW, you don't need the `EXPOSES 3333` in the Dockerfile since it's already done in the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access using localhost, you should share your host network interfaces with dockers. Otherwise, lo iface is different. 
Definitively, try with this docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:

  api:
    build: ./server
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"

  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: NoneOfYourBusiness

  web:
    build: ./web
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```